# Issue with integrating node-pty and XtermJS with VueJS in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, xtermjs

I was trying to integrate [node-pty](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty) and [xtermjs](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js) in an Electron App. I'm using VueJS for the frontend and want to create a Terminal interface inside the app. So how do I structure my code so that I can use it as a component like this:

`<Terminal></Terminal>`

I have tried the following but not able to get it fully working.

```
// Terminal.vue component.

<template>
  <v-container fluid class="pa-1">
    <div style="overflow-y:scroll!important" class="pa-1 black" id="terminal"></div>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import "xterm/css/xterm.css";
import { Terminal } from "xterm";
import { FitAddon } from "xterm-addon-fit";

const os = require("os");
const pty = require("node-pty");

const shell = process.env[os.platform() === "win32" ? "COMSPEC" : "SHELL"];

const ptyProc = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
  name: "xterm-color",
  env: process.env
});

const term = new Terminal({
  rows: 40,
  experimentalCharAtlas: "dynamic"
});

const fitAddon = new FitAddon();

term.loadAddon(fitAddon);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      term: null
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    console.log("entered");

    term.open(document.getElementById("terminal"));

    fitAddon.fit();

    term.onData(data => ptyProc.write(data));
    ptyProc.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      term.write(data);
    });

    term.onResize(size => {
      ptyProc.resize(
        Math.max(size ? size.cols : term.cols, 1),
        Math.max(size ? size.rows : term.rows, 1)
      );
    });

    console.log("exiting...");
  }
};
</script>
```

With the above code I have achieved the following interface:

[Terminal interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Nrh.png)

Here, a lot of features like terminal history, colors, some shorthand isn't working which were working fine with the vanilla javascript implementation below:

```
const {Terminal} = require('xterm');
const os = require('os');
const pty = require('node-pty');
const {FitAddon} = require('xterm-addon-fit');

const shell = process.env[os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'COMSPEC' : 'SHELL'];

const ptyProc = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
    name: 'xterm-color',
    env: process.env
});

const term = new Terminal({
    experimentalCharAtlas: 'dynamic',
    rows: 42
});

const fitAddon = new FitAddon();

term.loadAddon(fitAddon);
term.open(document.getElementById('opt1-panel'));
fitAddon.fit();

term.onData(data => ptyProc.write(data));
ptyProc.on('data', function(data){
    term.write(data);
});

term.onResize(size => {
    ptyProc.resize(
        Math.max(size ? size.cols : term.cols, 1),
        Math.max(size ? size.rows : term.rows, 1)
    );
});
```

The following image shows the result of above code which is a different project without vuejs.
[Using plain JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLOzW.png)

So how can I get it working in vuejs.

Just started learning VueJS and web stuff, so please excuse if its something obvious.

Comment: Found an implementation of the required component in ReactJS [link](https://github.com/loopmode/xpty). Not sure how to convert it to the VueJS component. Any help appreciated.